# how to take apart a number and multiply its digits?

Tags: java, c, loops, while-loop, numbers

hi I'm using codeblocks and I'm kinda new, 
I want to take apart a number and multiply its digits
and if number is > 9 then once again I want to take apart the digits and multiply them,
example: if I have the number 126 then the new number would be 1*2*6 = 12
but 12 is > 9 then once again the new number is 1*2 = 2, 2 is not >9 then get out of the loop 
thanks

Comment: int num;
    int newnum = 1;
    printf("Enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

      while (newnum > 9 ){
    digit = num %10;
    newnum *= digit;
    num /= 10;
    }

@MadushanPerera  I know I keep adding all the results of all the older numbers to the new one :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this program:

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String number = "126";
        int c = 1;
        for (int j =  number.length() ; j >=0; j--) {
        int v = j;
            for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
                String s = ""+number.charAt(i);
                c = c*  Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
            }

            System.out.println("result is : "+c);    
            c = 1;
        }        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in C:

```
int muldigits(unsigned int n) {
    while (n > 9) {
        unsigned int m = n;
        for (n = 1; m; n *= m % 10, m /= 10);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a function to work out each digit of the number you have inputted and then iterate until a zero is calculated. Something like this would work, and then just return the remainder of the switch statement:

```
quotient = number / 10; 
remainder = number % 10; 
switch(remainder)
{
    case 1:
        return 1
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can create a method to find number characters in the string like below:**

```
public static int Match(String pattern, String word) {
    int abc = 1;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(word);
    while (m.find()) {

        abc *= Integer.parseInt(m.group());
        System.out.println("val of abc when (m=" + m.group() + ") - " + abc);

    }
    System.out.println("*************************");
    return abc;
}
```

**Then you can check the given String inside your main method until you get the required number:**

```
    String word = "126 Florida Beach";
    String pattern = "\\d";

    int abc = 1;
    do {
        System.out.println("word at  - " + word);
        System.out.println("abc at - " + abc);
        abc = Match(pattern, word);
        word = String.valueOf(abc);

    } while (abc > 9);
    System.out.println("Required Value - " + abc);
```

Comment: @down-voter  may I know the reason ???